# Как на JS можно удалить столбец "Наименование"?

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите как правильно найти queryselector чтобы удалить столбец "Наименование" ?

https://jsfiddle.net/z2n3dm7b/1/

Сейчас скрипт удаляет только заголовок

```js
columns = document.querySelectorAll('th');

columns.forEach(function(column, position) {
 columnName = column.textContent.trim();
 
 if (columnName === 'Наименование') {
    column.remove();
    
    let rows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
     row.children[position].remove();
    });
 }

});
```

Comment: Упростите Ваш пример, а то минус поставлю Вам.

Comment: А html куда делся?

Comment: оставил по ссылке, к сожалению чтобы продемонстрировать работоспособность примера он нужен целиком, а так как вы попросили сократить я его удалил.
А также изначально уже отредактировал по максимуму исходный HTML насколько смог для публикации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все элементы с подобными именами и разными окончаниями будут найдены.

```js
// найдет все что начинается с "productTitle-"
for (let i of document.querySelectorAll("[id|=productTitle]")){
  console.log(i.id)
}
```

```html
<!-- Для примера простые элементы -->
<span id="productTitle-cell-0-71"><span>
<span id="productTitle-asd-2"><span>
<span id="productTitle-hlo-86"><span>
<span id="productTitle-75"><span>
<span id="productTitle-86-9"><span>
```

Comment: Спасибо сработало! Теперь понял как это можно было найти